# How do you retrieve the latest value from an array in MQL4?

Tags: arrays, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

How would I retrieve the latest value stored in an array in mql4? I need it so that the latest order open price is shown when I run my code below.

```
double OrderOpenPriceBuyArray[];
int count = 0;

ArraySetAsSeries(OrderOpenPriceBuyArray,True);

for(double n = 0; n < OrdersTotal(); n++){
if(OrderSelect(n,SELECT_BY_POS) && OrderType() == OP_BUY && OrderSymbol() == Symbol() 
){
if(OrderOpenPrice() != OrderOpenPriceBuyArray[count]){
OrderOpenPriceBuyArray[count] = OrderOpenPrice();
++count; 
}}
}

Print(OrderOpenPriceBuyArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method that you are using to retrieve the latest opening price is fundamentally flawed and will not work. Why not use:

```
datetime  latestBuyOrderOpen;
double    latestBuyOrderPrice;

void OnTick()
{
   for(int n=OrdersTotal()-1; n>=0; n--)
   {
      if(OrderSelect(n, SELECT_BY_POS) && OrderType()==OP_BUY && OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
      {
         if(OrderOpenTime()>latestBuyOrderOpen)
         {
            latestBuyOrderOpen=OrderOpenTime();
            latestBuyOrderPrice=OrderOpenPrice();
         }
      }
   }
   Comment(latestBuyOrderPrice);
}
```